# How to return the directory of the running .NET Core 2.2 app hosted on an Azure Windows Server VM?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, directory, system.io.file

So I have a .NET Core 2.2 app running on an Azure VM with Windows Server 2019 which has the following disk configuration:

[image: disk setup]

The disk on the red box is where the App files are located. Now, when `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is called by the app, it returns the root directory of the project and not the current directory where the app is running. When I tried to run it locally, it works.

To illustrate it:
When run locally, the directory `~/MyApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/` is returned by the call. When run in the VM, `~/MyApp/` is returned instead.

Here's the relevant code where the issue happens. What I do here is when the app is closed, it copies the current configuration file from `~/MyApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/` to the `~/MyApp/` directory. This code works when run on a local machine, but it is not when running on the VM. How to make sure that calling `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` does indeed point to the directory of the running app?

```
private void ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string rawConfigLocation = _config.GetSection("configurationSettings")["ConfigurationDirectory"];
            File.Delete($"{Path.Combine(rawConfigLocation, "Config.json.inc")}");

            using (var writer = File.CreateText($"{Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Config.json.inc")}"))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Config.json")))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream) writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                    writer.Close();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(rawConfigLocation);
                File.Move($"{Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Config.json.inc")}", $"{Path.Combine(rawConfigLocation, "Config.json.inc")}");
                File.Delete($"{Path.Combine(rawConfigLocation, "Config.json")}");
                File.Move($"{Path.Combine(rawConfigLocation, "Config.json.inc")}", $"{Path.Combine(rawConfigLocation, "Config.json")}");

                Debug.WriteLine($"New file saved as {Path.Combine(rawConfigLocation, "Config.json")}");

                #region [WINDOWS ONLY] Lines for debugging. Will be removed if the issue of incorrect config saving is fixed.

                using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("MyApp"))
                {
                    eventLog.Source = "MyApp";
                    eventLog.WriteEntry(
                        $"Raw Config Location: {_config.GetSection("configurationSettings")["ConfigurationDirectory"]}{Environment.NewLine}" +
                        $"File that was deleted: {Path.Combine(rawConfigLocation, "Config.json.inc")}{Environment.NewLine}" +
                        $"Temporary file created: {Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Config.json.inc")}{Environment.NewLine}" +
                        $"Current Directory: {Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{Environment.NewLine}" +
                        $"New file saved as {Path.Combine(rawConfigLocation, "Config.json")}",
                        EventLogEntryType.Information,
                        101,
                        1);
                }

                #endregion
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the folder structure?

Comment: @JimXu here: https://pastebin.com/rptNvDN5